# What's the largest object crossing Ceres' hill sphere?

Tags: asteroid-belt, ceres, hill-sphere

What's the largest and/or most massive main belt object whose Ceres MOID is within Ceres' hill sphere radius (within ~0.0015 a.u. (140,000 mi) (224,000 km))? Three-dimensionally, of course.

Comment: Some papers: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1104/1104.2028.pdf ... https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014acm..conf..476S/abstract